# How can I get envoyproxy/ratelimit statistics for descriptors without value?

Tags: rate-limiting, envoyproxy, statsd

I am using [envoyproxy/ratelimit](https://github.com/envoyproxy/ratelimit) (along with Istio) to setup a global rate limiting in my k8s cluster for a given service. The rate limit is based on a header (in my case the username) so that each username is limited by the number of RPS. The following configuration was used to achieve this:

```
    domain: ratelimit
    descriptors:
      - key: USERNAME
        rate_limit:
          unit: second
          requests_per_unit: 100
        shadow_mode: true
```

Also, I used a EnvoyFilter (Istio CRD) to define which header will used.

The resulting metric does not show a label for a specific user, just for the entire descriptor:

```
ratelimit_service_rate_limit_within_limit{app="ratelimit",domain="ratelimit",instance="xxx",job="kubernetes-pods",key1="USERNAME",kubernetes_namespace="xxx",kubernetes_pod_name="ratelimit-xxx",pod_template_hash="xxx",security_istio_io_tlsMode="istio",service_istio_io_canonical_name="ratelimit",service_istio_io_canonical_revision="latest"}
```

So my question is: how can I get the metrics for a specific username? Considering my configuration is applied to all of them and not for a specific value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this PR](https://github.com/envoyproxy/ratelimit/pull/389) you can now add a *detailed_metric* parameter to enable this behavior, as shown in [this example](https://github.com/envoyproxy/ratelimit#example-8).